# Importance of Algorithms in context of Mobile Application Development?

Tags: android, ios, algorithm, cocoa-touch

Is it really important to know algorithms to build mobile applications? I have strong understanding of development tools and design pattern as well as strong knowledge of OOP and MVC.

So, is it required to know hardcore algorithms to become a good mobile application developer?

---

I can understand that if you want to create games then YES it is obvious that we must know all the AI related algos to be competent. But I am asking for just simple data driven application building.

Comment: "algorithms" is very general, be more specific. it really depends on what you want to do..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every computer program you write implements an algorithm or a set of algorithms.  If you are concerned with the quality (deliberately vague term) of your programs then you have to be concerned with the quality of your algorithms.

For example, if you want your program to be fast (which is a quality that a program might have) better choose a fast algorithm than a slow algorithm for the same problem.  If you want your program to fit into a small amount of RAM (another quality factor) best choose an algorithm which operates in a small amount of RAM rather than one which gobbles it up by the GB.

So, critical knowledge for a software developer includes the knowledge of how to analyse an algorithm for speed, memory usage, and all the other quality factors you might be interested in optimising.  One way of analysing an algorithm is, of course, referring to texts which tell you what you want to know.

I conclude with the assertion that *yes you do need to know hardcore algorithms to be a good developer*, I don't see any reason to modify my belief when it comes to mobile applications development.  Of course, I don't expect you to know all about all the algorithms there might be, but the principal ones found in all the basic text books, and the ones which are specific to your application domain, *hell yes you gotta know those rascals !*

Comment: I agree... while it technically possible to write programs without a knowledge of algorithms, knowing algorithms can really help.  In my own app I use SQLite as my backing store.  But I cache indexes in memory and sort/filter using my own (and Apple's) algorithms.  This has speed up my app considerably since I don't have to go back to the DB to do my sorting or filtering.  Without knowledge of algorithms my app would have been a lot slower.

Comment: In fact, I would say it's more likely you need to understand efficient algorithms on a mobile device because mobile devices are much more constrained than any other platform.

Comment: i agree with you, but i also think that if more people concerned more about program readability and complexity more than performance, we would be in a better world

Comment: @Omar: so one of your software quality factors would be 'readability' and another 'complexity'.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Very helpful! I should better grok the algorithm books for optimisation of codes, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's irrelevant being for the mobile area or not. You should always try to achieve the best possible solution (there aren't perfect ones). In the mobile area, particulary, performance is very important, because we are talking about small devices, that although in recent years have been getting a major hardware boost, you should always take special care. I always use memory leaks to check if something is wrong with what I do. I also check the heap memory to see if there is something consuming too much memory. Battery is also a concern and you should also test if your application is using too much.

At the moment I am really focusing on the architecture of the application, a working application in the current standards (at least on my owns) is not enough. Knowing patterns is a powerful tool, and you should read about those (one of the best is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) one). Maintenance's costs are a major factor these days, and you should try to achieve the maximum code reusability and cleanness. Always assume that the client will change spec and always keep in mind that someone else in the future will maintain your code, so avoid long methods and over complex code (unless you have to do it). Also remember to leave comments, even if something is really simple, be humble... In a month you might not now what that "simple" stuff did. Those things are fairly easy to achieve when you are starting a project from scratch but a pain when you need to start thinking about those when the project is going to production in one week..

So as  for your question:  **is it required to know hardcore algorithms to become a good mobile application developer?**

My answer is: No, it helps, but there are others important parts when developing, besides algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Good algorithms can have a direct impact on battery consumption for your phone as well as how much of a memory footprint it has.  Every developer should strive to use the best algorithm possible, but that doesn't mean it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The smaller and more resource constrained your platform the more important it is to know algorithms. So on mobile it would be even more important.